# WKWebView Evaluate Javascript without reloading page

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, wkwebview

Currently I can only figure out how to evaluate javascript by adding it to the webview's configuration's userContentController and reloading the page like so:

```
WKUserScript *script = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:source injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];
[self.webView.configuration.userContentController addUserScript:script];
[self.webView reload];
```

How can I execute javascript on my WKWebView similarly to the old WebView's `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` so that I don't have to reload the page?

I'm trying to get something with the same effect as

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.querySelector('meta[name=viewport]').setAttribute('content', 'width=%d;', false); ", width]];
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
[webView evaluateJavaScript:javascriptString completionHandler:nil];
```

performs the same function as the one you have listed for UIWebView

Answer (score 9):

You can only set the `WKWebViewConfiguration` at init time via the initializer

```
[[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:configuration];
```

All calls to the property `configuration` are copied in a later stage of runtime (see docs and Header file). So basically what you´re doing with your first three lines of code is to set the `WKUserScript` to a `WKWebViewConfiguration` which is never used - and therefore not working.

The right way to do it:

```
NSString *scriptString = @"Some javascript";
WKUserScript *script = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:scriptString injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];
WKUserContentController *userContentController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
[userContentController addUserScript:script];
WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
configuration.userContentController = userContentController;
_webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:configuration];
```

After doing this, you won´t need `evaluateJavaScript:` anymore.

P.S.: I´m using this code in my little project [`STKWebKitViewController` on GitHub](https://github.com/sticksen/STKWebKitViewController). Maybe this will save you time, too!

Comment: what if you need to make consecutive calls to the web page? Would you call addUserScript every time?

Comment: Please define "consecutive". This approach runs the same JavaScript(s) on every page load. If you want to alter which scripts are being executed, evaluateJavaScript: may be the better solution for you.

Comment: Say you need to call the function and pass the current timestamp as  an argument on every uibutton click.How would you do it?

Comment: Definitely `evaluateJavaScript:`! As you can see in the above code, with the WKUserScripts it´s only possible to execute at document start or end, not for custom events such as button clicks.