# postMessage() is not working in WKWebView(iOS, objective c)

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, iphone, wkwebview

I am trying using WKWebView to load my local html file and want to send postMessage to my html , but postMessage is not working, WKWebView is unable to load the html file.

Loading WKWebView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    WKUserContentController* userController = [[WKUserContentController alloc]init];
   theConfiguration.userContentController = userController;




    _twkwebview = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:theConfiguration];

    NSString *indexHTMLPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:indexHTMLPath];

    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theConfiguration.userContentController
     addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"interOp"];


    [_twkwebview loadRequest:nsrequest];
     [self setupPostMessageScript];
    [self.test addSubview:_twkwebview];

}
```

From here, I want to post the message, but it's not working. I'm not getting any errors, here is the source(html):

```
- (void)setupPostMessageScript {

        NSString *source = @"window.originalPostMessage = window.postMessage;"
        "window.postMessage = function(message, targetOrigin, transfer) {"
        "window.webkit.messageHandlers.interOp.postMessage(message);"
        "if (typeof targetOrigin !== 'undefined') {"
        "window.originalPostMessage(message, targetOrigin, transfer);"
        "}"
        "};";



    WKUserScript *script = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:source
                                                  injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentStart
                                               forMainFrameOnly:false];
    [_twkwebview.configuration.userContentController addUserScript:script];

}
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(__unused WKNavigation *)navigation
{

    [self setupPostMessageScript];


}
```

In html I have added `document.addEventListener` to get my posted message but its never getting called:

```
 document.addEventListener('message', function(e) {

        let message = JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log('MEssaget typ recieved '+message);
});
```

What is the correct way to postMessage from objective C, html?

Comment: Maybe this would help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24877319/7292964 I don't think `addUserScript` is quite what you want for this case.

Comment: @Samantha I want to post message from objective c code to js code , same as back from js code to objective c code , first part is not working

Comment: Sorry, I just thought that `[webView evaluateJavaScript: completionHandler:]` might be a better way of executing that part, as in that question it seems you have to reload the webView for added user scripts to take effect. In general I didn't think that adding user scripts after loading had any effect, but I could be wrong.